# Adding SlideUp and slidedown animation on replaceWith in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a app showcase site. I have a page with full width vertical slides . I added a fixed phone on the screen. I want to add a image on the phone when the user slide it using button.

When he press the button the jquery remove the current image from the phone and add a  new image in a sliding manner. I have found a tutorial on codyhouse https://codyhouse.co/demo/app-introduction-template/index.html#cd-product-tour.

It's a good tutorial but not able to do it in a vertical way. My code of the slides is this

```
    <div id="allslides">
        <div  id="1" class="slides" phone_image='its the url of the image going to be added on the phone when the slide is active  '>   
            <h1>My Appp</h1>
            <p class='content'>Some content</p>         
        </div>
       <div  id="2" class="slides" phone_image='its the url of the image going to be added on the phone when the slide is active  '>    
            <h1>My Appp</h1>
            <p class='content'>Some content</p>         
        </div>
<div  id="3" class="slides" phone_image='its the url of the image going to be added on the phone when the slide is active  '>   
            <h1>My Appp</h1>
            <p class='content'>Some content</p>         
        </div>
<div  id="4" class="slides" phone_image='its the url of the image going to be added on the phone when the slide is active  '>   
            <h1>My Appp</h1>
            <p class='content'>Some content</p>         
        </div>
    </div>
```

I give the .slides the width and height 100%. The slider is working great and the phone is fixed on the screen perfectly. But I want the phone image to change on every slide And it effect should be same as on the link but with vertical way.

My navigation button code is this

```
<div id="navigation">
                <ul>
<li><a href="#" class="bullets" id="bullet1" onclick="slider(1)"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bullets" id="bullet2" onclick="slider(2)"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bullets" id="bullet3" onclick="slider(3)"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="bullets" id="bullet4" onclick="slider(4)"></a></li>
                </ul>
    </div>
```

The phone of the html is this

```
 <div class="phone">
            <div class="cd-image-container">
                <div>
                    <div class="cd-phone-frame"></div>
                    <div class="cd-image-wrapper">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
            </div>
```

The jQuery that I am using is this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".bullets").first().addClass('activeBullet');

            var image = $("#1").attr('phone_image');
            $('.cd-image-wrapper').prepend('<img src="'+image+'"data-video="video/video-2" alt="Screen Preview 2">');
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.cd-image-wrapper img').slideDown("fast");
            },1);
});

The slider function is this 

function slider(n){

var ID = $(".activeDiv").attr("id");
            var sid= ID.split("slide"); 
            var new_id = sid[1];

            if(new_id == n){

            }else{


                $(".slides").removeClass('activeDiv');
                $("#slide"+n).addClass('activeDiv');

                var top = $("#slide"+n).position().top;

                $("#mainbar").css({'top':-top});

                $(".bullets").removeClass('activeBullet');
                $("#bullet"+n).addClass('activeBullet');        $('.cd-image-wrapper img').fadeOut("slow", function(){
                    var images = $("#"+id).attr('phone_image');
                    var div = $('<img src="'+images+'"data-video="video/video-2" alt="Screen Preview 2">').hide();
                    $(this).replaceWith(div);
                    $('.cd-image-wrapper img').fadeIn("slow");
                });

            }                       
            }
```

As you can see I am able to make the phone image change effect in fadeout and fadeIn manner. Anyone can tell me how to do it in slidedown and slideup way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite understand what you mean. I can't add a comment so just write here.
If you mean you want click a button and the DIV slide.
You can just use css animate like [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/?#cta)

first make the div you want slideIn position:absolute top:100%;
 and the div you want slideOut position:absolute top:0;

then when you click button add css animate class to slideIn Div make it top:0, slideOut div top: -100%; It will work and also you can add other animation like change the opacity to it.

It's will be easy to use css animate here the  [Using CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)

Answer (score 0):

You can use slide effect from jQuery UI.

Here you have a [working sample of the effect](https://jqueryui.com/effect/): choose slide in the select and run then click "Run effect".

You can modify the direction and distance of the effect, as [documented here](http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/).